# ASP.Net SqlWebEventProvider - Raising custom event - Cannot access WebErrorEvent due its protection level

Tags: asp.net, provider

I use SqlWebEventProvider to log the exceptions to sql server, and it works fine.

I also want to log custom exceptions to aspnet_WebEvent_Events table programmatically. Similar to - http://fredrik.nsquared2.com/viewpost.aspx?PostID=107&showfeedback=true

WebBaseEvent.Raise(new WebErrorEvent("My Error message", null, 5000, e));
I get an error saying "Cannot access constructor 'WebErrorEvent' here due its protection level.

Appreciate your comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to log custom events, you may consider creating your own event by inheriting from one of the predefined event classes found in System.Web.Management.

Here is a good reference written by Scott Mitchell. It is pretty easy to follow
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121454/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062707-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for class `WebErrorEvent` is private. You can't instantiate an object of this class.

Take a look at Using Access Modifier private with Constructor in the article titled [What are constructors in CSharp - A Step Ahead Series?](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/26131-What-are-constructors-CSharp-A-Step-Ahead.aspx).